# Ignore Serialize field based on another field value

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson

I have a class like this:

```
public class Profile {
        private String firstName;
        private String lastName;
        private String nickName;
        @JsonIgnore
        private boolean isNameSecret;
}
```

when serialising the object is possible to hide the properties `firstName` and `lastName` if the value of `isNameSecret` is `true`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to write custom serialiser and implement that logic. It could look like below:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonSerializer;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationFeature;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonSerialize;

import java.io.IOException;

public class ProfileApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);
        System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(new Profile()));
    }
}

class ProfileJsonSerialize extends JsonSerializer<Profile> {

    @Override
    public void serialize(Profile profile, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider serializers) throws IOException {
        gen.writeStartObject();
        if (!profile.isNameSecret()) {
            gen.writeStringField("firstName", profile.getFirstName());
            gen.writeStringField("lastName", profile.getLastName());
        }
        gen.writeStringField("nickName", profile.getNickName());
        gen.writeEndObject();
    }
}

@JsonSerialize(using = ProfileJsonSerialize.class)
class Profile {

    private String firstName = "Rick";
    private String lastName = "Sanchez";
    private String nickName = "Pickle Rick";
    private boolean isNameSecret = true;

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getNickName() {
        return nickName;
    }

    public void setNickName(String nickName) {
        this.nickName = nickName;
    }

    public boolean isNameSecret() {
        return isNameSecret;
    }

    public void setNameSecret(boolean nameSecret) {
        isNameSecret = nameSecret;
    }
}
```

Above code prints:

```
{
  "nickName" : "Pickle Rick"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved using Jackson's [Mixin](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-docs/wiki/JacksonMixInAnnotations) feature. it allows to apply annotations from an external class at run time. the match is done by specifying the same property names (works also on method names like getter/setter)

Here is an example according to the question (made instance variables public for simplicity) notice that the mixin class contains only the properties you want to override. also, it need not be initialized.

mixin class with same property names and added annotations

```
public class ProfileIgnoreFirstLastName
{
    @JsonIgnore
    public String firstName;
    @JsonIgnore
    public String lastName;
}
```

serialization with conditional apply of mixin class:

```
public static String serializeProfile(Profile profile) throws IOException {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    if (profile.isNameSecret) {
        mapper.addMixIn(Profile.class, ProfileIgnoreFirstLastName.class);
    }
    return mapper.writeValueAsString(profile);
}
```

test method

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        Profile profile = new Profile();
        profile.isNameSecret = false;
        System.out.println(serializeProfile(profile));
        profile.isNameSecret = true;
        System.out.println(serializeProfile(profile));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

output

```
{"firstName":"my first name","lastName":"my last name","nickName":"my nick name"}
{"nickName":"my nick name"}
```