# Update the JSON element to NULL if it has a specific value in it

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, jackson

I have a JSON which looks like,

```
{
 "person": {
  "name":"Sam", 
  "surname":"ngonma"
 },
 "car": {
  "make":"toyota", 
  "model":"yaris"
 }
}
```

I am writing this to Amazon SQS with the below lines,

```
ObjectMapper mObjectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
sqsExtended.sendMessage(new SendMessageRequest(awsSQSUrl, mObjectMapper.writeValueAsString(claim)));
```

I have a separate array of values, if the JSON has its value in that array I have to write the field as `null`.

If my string array is `["Sam", "Toyota"]` my final JSON should look like this,

```
{
 "person": {
  "name":null, 
  "surname":"ngonma"
 },
 "car": {
  "make":null, 
  "model":"yaris"
 }
}
```

The string array is externalized. It may have additional values in future too. Could someone suggest me a good link or idea to address this ?

Comment: Get your claim-object right BEFORE you start serializing it to JSON?

Comment: @Mick, what is "claim-object"?

Comment: the object called "claim" in your example

Comment: You need to write custom serialiser for `POJO` class or do that on `POJO` before serialisation. See [Ignore Serialize field based on another field value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54989412/ignore-serialize-field-based-on-another-field-value)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most flexible way I could come up with is to use Jackson's [JsonAnyGetter](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-annotations) annotation. It allows you to provide Jackson with a `Map` representation of the state of your pojo. filtering values from a `Map` can be done in iterative way. filtering values from a `Map` that contains `Map`s can be done in recursive way.

Here is a solution I built from provided question

```
public class Claim {
    Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();

    public Claim() {
        // may be populated from instance variables
        Map<String, String> person = new HashMap<>();
        person.put("name", "Sam");
        person.put("surname", "ngonma");
        properties.put("person", person);
        Map<String, String> car = new HashMap<>();
        car.put("make", "Toyota");
        car.put("model", "yaris");
        properties.put("car", car);
    }

    // nullify map values based on provided array
    public void filterProperties (String[] nullifyValues) {
        filterProperties(properties, nullifyValues);
    }

    // nullify map values of provided map based on provided array
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private void filterProperties (Map<String, Object> properties, String[] nullifyValues) {
        // iterate all String-typed values
        // if value found in array arg, nullify it
        // (we iterate on keys so that we can put a new value)
        properties.keySet().stream()
            .filter(key -> properties.get(key) instanceof String)
            .filter(key -> Arrays.asList(nullifyValues).contains(properties.get(key)))
            .forEach(key -> properties.put(key, null));
        // iterate all Map-typed values
        // call this method on value
        properties.values().stream()
            .filter(value -> value instanceof Map)
            .forEach(value -> filterProperties((Map<String, Object>)value, nullifyValues));
    }

    // provide jackson with Map of all properties
    @JsonAnyGetter
    public Map<String, Object> getProperties() {
        return properties;
    }
}
```

test method

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        Claim claim = new Claim();
        claim.filterProperties(new String[]{"Sam", "Toyota"});
        System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(claim));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

output

`{"car":{"model":"yaris","make":null},"person":{"surname":"ngonma","name":null}}`

Comment: Thanks @Sharon. That works fine. But I have a complex JSON i.e, nested objects, nested array of objects. Can you help me converting that to Map. My actual JSON here - (http://meetingwords.com/smbalu-claimJSON).

Comment: perhaps this can help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39543926/how-to-convert-pojo-to-map-and-vice-versa-in-java (see accepted answer)