# How to filter serialization based on another field's value?

Tags: java, json, jackson

I've read [this article](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-serialize-field-custom-criteria) which describes Jackson filtering and scoured the internet but cannot determine a way to filter one field based on another field.

Suppose I have this class:

```java
public class Address {
    private int zip;
    private String city;
    private String streetAddress;
    private String state;
}
```

How would I set up a serialization filter such that whenever the zipcode starts with a 9, the state is left out? I need to use a `SimpleBeanPropertyFilter`.

For example:

```java
Address(90000, "Prunedale", "123 Localhost", "Vermont")
// {"zip": 90000, "city": "Prunedale", "streetAddress": "123 Localhost"}

Address(80000, "Prunedale", "123 Localhost", "Vermont")
// {"zip": 80000, "city": "Prunedale", "streetAddress": "123 Localhost", "state": "Vermont"}
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: During serialisation process you need an access to two properties: `zip` and `state` so I suggest to implement custom serialiser which checks conditions and writes or not given field. See similar question and solution: [Ignore Serialize field based on another field value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54989412/ignore-serialize-field-based-on-another-field-value/54992544#54992544)

Comment: Is there a way to then ignore fields with empty or null values automatically? Or would I need to manually check each field before writing?